# When pushing a new view controller to my navigation controller, I get returned the the same view controller I tapped from instead of the new one

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, uikit

I have a UIViewController that has a UITableView added as a subview. When I tap on a cell to return a new UIViewController (detail view controller, empty aside from background color) I get returned the same starting view controller and table view.

I am using navigationController.pushViewController(), but I have the same issue with present(). I am led to believe that I am calling the wrong view controller but when using the debug view hierarchy my detail view controller appears to be a copy of the main view controller. I can't figure out why because the detail view controller is mostly empty. I'm also sure I have the scene delegate set up correctly with the navigation controller set to the root view.

This is the tableView code, the variable "countries" is an array of strings. I have tried using self.navigationController?.pushViewController() and nothing changes.

```
extension ViewController : UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return countries.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: FlagCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as! FlagCell
        let country = countries[indexPath.row]
        let image = UIImage(named: country)
        cell.flagImageView.image = image
        cell.countryNameLabel.text = country
        return cell
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 80
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let vc = FlagViewController()
        navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Here is the code for the detail view controller.

```
import UIKit

class FlagViewController: ViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.backgroundColor = .systemMint
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This line is likely your problem:

```
let vc = FlagViewController()
```

If you create a view controller like that, it won't get views from a storyboard or nib-file. The only way I know of to create a view controller by calling an initializer with no parameters like this is if that view controller implements `loadView()` method and builds its view hierarchy in code.

Unless you're created your `FlagViewController`'s view hierarchy in code, you probably want to load it from a storyboard using the `UIStoryboard` method `instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:)`.

Comment: Ok to update, the app is sending 2 views, the main view and the detail view. If I reduce the constraints, I can see a new tableview load underneath the detail view.

Comment: You said "the app is sending 2 views..." I don't know what "sending views" means. Use specific, appropriate terms like "pushing" (onto a nav stack) or "presenting" (modally.)

Comment: Also, don't conflate views and view **controllers**. A view is something that shows up on-screen. A view controller implements business logic and manages views. They are not the same thing, and you'll cause confusion (to yourself and others) if you mix up the terms.

Comment: Ok thank you for the explanation and advice. My detail view controller class was conforming to "ViewController" (The name of my main view controller) instead of "UIViewController" so it was pushing the subviews from both classes.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you it seems that I needed more code for the view hierarchy, I am confused because I've seen many tutorials and articles that had identical code to mine to do similar jobs but it is what it is. I used viewDidLoad() but please tell me if it is recommended to use didLoad()

Heres the final update of the new viewController

```
let flagView: UIView = {
    let flagView = UIView()
    flagView.backgroundColor = .systemMint
    return flagView
}()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    setupUI()
}


// MARK: - UI Setup
private func setupUI() {
    self.view.addSubview(flagView)
    flagView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    
    
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        flagView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor),
        flagView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor),
        flagView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor),
        flagView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor),
        
        flagView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor),
        flagView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerYAnchor),
    ])
}
```

Comment: You are missing the key point from my answer: Every time your user selects a cell in your `ViewController` class, you are creating a new instance of your `FlagViewController` and presenting it on top of the existing pile of modals in your UI. That is wrong.